# change wordpress customizer input with js

Tags: wordpress

I want to change wp customizer input field value with js.
When I do something like this:

```
$('#customize-control-blogname').find('input').val('Test');
```

input gets that text ("Test") but when I hit "Save" old value gets saved not "Test". Like change is not registered by wp.

Comment: This helps $('#customize-control-blogname').find('input').trigger('change');